# Using grep to find function

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I need to find the usage of functions like `system("rm filename")` & `system("rm -r filename")`.

I tried `grep -r --include=*.{cc,h} "system" .` & `grep -r --include=*.{cc,h} "rm" .` but they are giving too many outcomes.

How do I search for all the instances of `system("rm x")` where 'x' can be anything. Kind of new with grep.

Comment: `grep -r 'system("rm'`

Comment: I'd add a space to that pattern, aragaer.  But calls to `rmdir` or similar should be rare anyway.

Comment: For files, better use the  [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) syscall or the  [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) library function that calling `system("rm`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bsh
grep -E "system\(\"rm [a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\"\)" file.txt
```

Regexp `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` builds a pattern for `grep` what it needs to find in `x` of `system("rm x")`. Unfortunately, `grep` don't supports groups for matching, so you will need to specify it directly what to search.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way might be to work inside the GCC compiler. You could use the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) domain specific language for that. It provides easy matching on Gimple internal representation of GCC.

It is more complex than textual solutions, but it would also find e.g. calls to `system` inside functions after inlining and other optimizations.

<sup>So customizing the GCC compiler is probably not worth the effort for your case, unless you have a really large code base (e.g. million of lines of source code).</sup>

In a simpler textual based approach, you might pipe two greps, e.g.

```
   grep -rwn system * | grep -w rm
```

or perhaps just

```
   grep -rn 'system.*rm' *
```

BTW, in some big enough software, you may probably have a lot of code like e.g.

```
  char cmdbuf[128];
  snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "rm %s", somefilepath);
  system (cmdbuf);
```

and in that case a simple textual `grep` based approach is not enough (unless you inspect visually surrounding code).

Answer (score 0):

Install `ack` (http://beyondgrep.com) and your call is:

```
ack --cc '\bsystem\(.+\brm\rb'
```